# Django datefield filter by weekday/weekend

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I've got a date_created field in my database:

`date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)`

Is there some way I could filter date_created by weekend/weekday? I know that python's date.weekday() returns 0 - 6 depending on days of the week, so I'd like to use something like:

```
apps.objects.filter(date_created__weekday >=5) // filter by weekend
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Django comes with a weekday field lookup.

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day

Comment: N.B. the django ORM week_day lookup returns 1-7 for Su-Sat instead of the usual 0-6 M-Su