# Django query: more on weekends or weekdays

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=42)

class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I find all users who have more actions on weekends (sunday and saturday) than on other days of week and vice versa?

Edit: I don't need to check this condition for one user, that would be easy. I need to select all users who have one of these conditions hold true.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600325/django-datefield-filter-by-weekday-weekend

Comment: @PaulTomblin I know how to simply select by weekday, but I need to efficiently select users who have more actions on weekends, than on another days.

Comment: Can't you do a `.count()` after you've written the select by weekday?

Comment: @PaulTomblin I need to do this comparison for all users.

Comment: In SQL you could maybe do something with `EXTRACT(DOW FROM timestamp)`  (which is in PostgreSQL but I don't know if it's portable) but the only way I know of to do this in Django would be to write your own custom subclass of `django.db.models.sql.aggregates.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one query with the extra method, passing a custom statement in the WHERE clause. This MySQL example selects all users where the number of actions during the weekend is less than or equal to the number of actions on other days:

```
f = {
    'user_table': User._meta.db_table,
    'action_table': Action._meta.db_table,
    'user_id': User._meta.pk.get_attname_column()[1],
    'user_fk': Action._meta.get_field('user').get_attname_column()[1],
    'timestamp': Action._meta.get_field('timestamp').get_attname_column()[1],
}

query = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %(action_table)s \
    WHERE %(action_table)s.%(user_fk)s = %(user_table)s.%(user_id)s \
    AND DAYOFWEEK(%(action_table)s.%(timestamp)s IN (1,7)) \
    <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %(action_table)s \ 
    WHERE %(action_table)s.%(user_fk)s = %(user_table)s.%(user_id)s \
    AND DAYOFWEEK(%(action_table)s.%(timestamp)s) NOT IN (1,7))" % f
users = User.objects.extra(where=[query]))
```

The syntax might be slightly different for backends other than MySQL. You should of course alter the table- and columnnames for your situation.

Comment: Thanks, doing it this way, just using introspection to get column/table names and compose query.

Comment: Updated my answer to include introspection to get column/table names.